# Fixed point question without knowledge of metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Everything is in $\mathbb{R}$ and we define $\mathbb{R}$ the set of all Cauchy sequences which is complete.

Given a recursive sequence $a_n = f(a_{n-1})$ where $f$ is a continuous function and differentiable.

The task is to show that $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and identifying the limit.

Usually with these kind of questions showing the limit is easy but showing that its Cauchy is hard. I've seen multiple posts of these questions and it all used fixed-point theorem whether it be Banach or not.

The method I am asked to use is the mean value theorem and the usage of geometric series. And geometric series is applied in the fixed point questions **easily** because usually the $0 \leq r <1$ is given.

**Question:** How can I find this $r$?

$|f(a_{n+1})-f(a_n)| \leq |f'(c)||a_{n+1}-a_n|$ by the mean value theorem so how can I guarentee that this $r =|f'(c)|$ to be $[0,1)$

For example, consider $a_n = cos(a_{n-1})$ how can I show that this is Cauchy without ANY knowledge of metric spaces. This is generic example that's on multiple posts it always used the knowledge of metric spaces and the "$r$" was always given to be in between $[0,1)$.

I am aware my questions is very vague but I tried my best writing what my question would be if any more information is needed please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: In your example $a_n=\cos(a_{n-1})$, what is the first element, i.e. what is $a_1$?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention that. $a_1 =1$

Comment: Can you use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition to bound $\mid f(a_{n+1})-f(a_n) \mid$ and $\mid a_{n+1}-a_n \mid$?

Comment: I tried but I don't think I can...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove that the sequence is Cauchy. For example $f(x)=x+1$ is differentiable but $(a_n)$ is not Cauchy in this case.